# Escape Backslash with String Combination

Tags: python-3.x, module, backslash

I am working on a program that clicks a button when it changes color, and at the end of the program, it screenshots the webpage, saves the screenshot, and then moves it to a different directory. Everything seems to be working fine except for moving the file into a different folder. The code I am using to move the file is here:

```
os.replace("'\\'" + fileName, "'\\'" + saveName + "'\\'" + fileName)
```

I get the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: "'\'0.png" -> "'\'saves216'\'0.png"

I don't know how to get the backslash to escape without becoming a double backslash

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra quotes:

```
os.replace("\\" + fileName, "\\" + saveName + "\\" + fileName)
```

You directly escape a `\` with another one:

```
>>> s = "\\" + "filename"
>>> print(s)
\filename
```

Comment: The question lacks information in that case, post information about your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.replace("\\" + fileName, "\\" + saveName + "\\" + fileName)
```

extra '' in yours

change the filename variable too if it has ''

Comment: Gives the error:
unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: your error shows multiple ' in the path  "'\'saves216'\'0.png"